# change displaying values in the pickers modal material-ui-pickers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, time-format

How to make date format in German like: Fr.,17. Mai?

The sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/hopeful-haibt-ruktp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment` does not come loaded with all possible language files. It only loads one language without configuration, and that language is english.

You have to import the language file and set the locale on an instance of `moment`. You also have to add `moment` as a prop to the `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` as well as the `locale`:

```
import moment from 'moment';

import 'moment/locale/de';

moment.locale('de');

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils} locale="de" moment={moment} />
```

Comment: I imported german localization from moment, but it didn't help

Comment: @fetchenko I have updated my answer. Some things were left out in my thought process.

Comment: Yes, it changed time format. Thanks
But do you know how to set up format like Fr.,17. Mai?

Comment: @fetchenko Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer if it helped solving your problem.